# Remove Option From Tool

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, liquid

I had a wetsuit size picker created by another developer but I now want to remove a question from the survey. The one I need to be removed is "experience level". I hope this won't affect the algorithm to choose a suit. From what I can see, I think it is `<div class="Experience-section">`

Can someone please help with this? Below is the current code. Let me know if you need any more info or a link to anything else.

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="height-background">
<div class="page-width">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid__item medium-up--four-fifths medium-up--push-one-tenth">
      <div class="rte">
        {{ page.content }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Height-section">
    <div class="slidecontainer">
       <div class="section-header text-center">
         <h3 class="head-text h3">FIND YOUR FIT</h3>
         <h1 class="section-header__title h2">Enter Your Height</h1>
       </div>
       <p class="height-numbers">I'M THIS TALL : <output>130cm</output> - <span id="demo">4 foot 3"</span></p>   
            <input type="range" min="123" max="195" value="130" list="ticks1" class="slider" id="myRange">
            <datalist id="range-ticks1">
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
            </datalist>
            <datalist id="range-ticks2">
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
            </datalist>
      <div class="RangeSlider_TrackFill"></div>
      <button class="height-submt">FIND MY PERFECT WETSUIT</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="weight-section">
    <div class="slidecontainer">
       <div class="section-header text-center">
         <h3 class="head-text h3">FIND YOUR FIT</h3>
         <h1 class="section-header__title h2">Enter Your Weight</h1>
       </div>
      <p class="weight-numbers">I WEIGHT : <output class="weight-output">55 Kg</output> - <span id="demo1">121.25 lbs</span></p>   
            <input type="range" min="40" max="100" value="55" class="slider1" id="myRange1">
            <datalist id="range-ticks1">
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
            </datalist>
            <datalist id="range-ticks2">
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
            </datalist>
      <div class="btn-section">
        <button class="back-btn">BACK</button>
      <button class="weight-submt">CONTINUE</button>  
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
  
  <div class="gender-section">
    <div class="section-header text-center">
         <h3 class="head-text h3">FIND YOUR FIT</h3>
         <h1 class="section-header__title h2">My Gender Is</h1>
       </div>
    <div class="select-male">
      <div class="man-image">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2374/2623/files/man.png" class="man" alt="man">
      </div>
      <div class="male-btn"> 
        <button class="Male">MALE</button>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="select-female">
      <div class="women-image">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2374/2623/files/women.png" class="woman" alt="woman">
    </div>
        <div class="female-btn">   
        <button class="Female">FEMALE</button>
      </div>
    </div>   
      <div class="btn-section">
        <button class="back-btn">BACK</button>
      </div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="Body-shape-section">
    <div class="section-header text-center">
         <h3 class="head-text h3">FIND YOUR FIT</h3>
         <h1 class="section-header__title h2">Selet Your Body Shape</h1>
       </div>
    <div class="select-male-s">
      <div class="women-image">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2374/2623/files/man.png" class="man" alt="man">
      </div>
      <div class="male-btn"> 
        <button class="Male">SLIM</button>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="select-male-r">
      <div class="women-image">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2374/2623/files/regular-man.png" class="man" alt="woman">
    </div>
        <div class="male-btn">   
        <button class="Male">REGULAR</button>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="select-male-l">
      <div class="women-image">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2374/2623/files/large-man.png" class="man" alt="woman">
    </div>
        <div class="male-btn">   
        <button class="Male">LARGE</button>
      </div>
    </div>  
      <div class="btn-section">
        <button class="back-btn">BACK</button>
      </div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="Female-Body-shape-section">
    <div class="section-header text-center">
         <h3 class="head-text h3">FIND YOUR FIT</h3>
         <h1 class="section-header__title h2">Select Your Body Shape</h1>
       </div>
    <div class="select-female-s">
      <div class="woman-image">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2374/2623/files/women.png" class="man" alt="man">
      </div>
      <div class="female-btn"> 
        <button class="Female">SLIM</button>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="select-female-r">
      <div class="man-image">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2374/2623/files/regular-women.png" class="man" alt="woman">
    </div>
        <div class="female-btn">   
        <button class="Female">REGULAR</button>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="select-female-l">
      <div class="man-image">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2374/2623/files/large-women.png" class="man" alt="woman">
    </div>
        <div class="female-btn">   
        <button class="Female">LARGE</button>
      </div>
    </div>  
      <div class="btn-section">
        <button class="back-btn">BACK</button>
      </div>
  </div>  
  
   <div class="Select-preferred-fit-section">
    <div class="section-header text-center">
         <h3 class="head-text h3">FIND YOUR FIT</h3>
         <h1 class="section-header__title h2">Select Your Preferred Fit</h1>
       </div>
    <div class="select-tight">
      <div class="tight-btn"> 
        <button class="tight">TIGHT</button>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="select-standard">
        <div class="standard-btn">   
        <button class="standard">STANDARD</button>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="select-lesstight">
        <div class="lesstight-btn">   
        <button class="lesstight">LESS TIGHT</button>
      </div>
    </div>  
      <div class="btn-section">
        <button class="back-btn">BACK</button>
        <button class="rate-submt">CONTINUE</button>  
      </div>
  </div> 
  {%-comment-%}
  <div class="Experience-section">
    <div class="slidecontainer">
       <div class="section-header text-center">
         <h3 class="head-text h3">FIND YOUR FIT</h3>
         <h1 class="section-header__title h2">Enter Your Experience</h1>
       </div>
       <p class="expirience-numbers">I RATE MY SKILLS : <span id="demo2"></span> out of 5</p>   
            <input type="range" min="1" max="5" value="4" class="slider" id="myRange2">
            <datalist id="range-ticks3">
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
            </datalist>
            <datalist id="range-ticks4">
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
            </datalist>
      <div class="msg"><span id="msg-demo"></span> out of 5, I am an experienced Tri Athlete</div>
       <div class="btn-section">
        <button class="back-btn">BACK</button>
      <button class="rate-submt">CONTINUE</button>  
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {%-endcomment-%}
  
</div> 
</div>  
  
<script>

var $element = $('#myRange');
var $output = $('output');
function updateOutput(el, val) {
  el.textContent = val;
}

function toFeet(n) {
      var realFeet = ((n*0.392700) / 12);
      var feet = Math.floor(realFeet);
      var inches = Math.round((realFeet - feet) * 12);
      return feet + "&nbsp;" + "foot"+ "&nbsp;" + inches + '"';
    }

$element
  .slider({
    polyfill: false,
    rangeClass: 'slider',
    //disabledClass: 'rangeslider--disabled',
    //horizontalClass: 'rangeslider--horizontal',
    //verticalClass: 'rangeslider--vertical',
    onInit: function() {
      updateOutput($output[0], this.value + '"' );
      $("#demo").html(toFeet(this.value));
    },
   
  })

  .on('input', function() {
    updateOutput($output[0], this.value + '\xa0' + 'cm' );
    $("#demo").html(toFeet(this.value));
    
  });

</script>
  
<!---<script>
var slider1 = document.getElementById("myRange1");
var output1 = document.getElementById("demo1");
output1.innerHTML = slider1.value;

slider1.oninput = function() {
  output1.innerHTML = this.value;
}
  </script>--->

<script>

var $element = $('input[type="range"].slider1');
var $output1 = $('.weight-output');
function updateOutput(el, val) {
  el.textContent = val;
}

function kToLbs(pK) {
    var nearExact = pK/0.45359237;
    var Kg  = Math.floor(nearExact)
    var lbs = Math.round((nearExact-Kg)* 100);
    return Kg + "." + lbs + "&nbsp;" + 'lbs';
    }

  
  $element
  .slider({
    polyfill: false,
    rangeClass: 'slider1',
    //disabledClass: 'rangeslider--disabled',
    //horizontalClass: 'rangeslider--horizontal',
    //verticalClass: 'rangeslider--vertical',
    onInit: function() {
      updateOutput($output1[0], this.value + '"' );
      $("#demo1").html(kToLbs(this.value));
    },
   
  })

  .on('input', function() {
    updateOutput($output1[0], this.value + '\xa0' + 'Kg' );
    $("#demo1").html(kToLbs(this.value));
    
  });

</script>
  

<script>
var slider2 = document.getElementById("myRange2");
var output2 = document.getElementById("demo2");
output2.innerHTML = slider2.value;

slider2.oninput = function() {
  output2.innerHTML = this.value ;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   
$(document).ready(function(){
  
   $('.weight-section').hide();
   $('.gender-section').hide();
    $('.Body-shape-section').hide();
    $('.Female-Body-shape-section').hide();
    $('.Select-preferred-fit-section').hide();
    $('.Experience-section').hide();
    $('.height-submt').on('click', function() {
       
        $('.weight-section').show();
      $('.Height-section').hide();
   
  });
  
    
   $('.gender-section').hide();
    $('.Body-shape-section').hide();
    $('.Female-Body-shape-section').hide();
    $('.Select-preferred-fit-section').hide();
    $('.Experience-section').hide();
  $('.weight-section button.back-btn').on('click', function() {
    
       $('.Height-section').show();
        $('.weight-section').hide();
   
  });
  
  $('.gender-section').hide();
    $('.Body-shape-section').hide();
    $('.Female-Body-shape-section').hide();
    $('.Select-preferred-fit-section').hide();
    $('.Experience-section').hide();
    $('.weight-submt').on('click', function() {
       
      $('.gender-section').show();
      $('.weight-section').hide();
   
  });
  
  $('.Body-shape-section').hide();
    $('.Female-Body-shape-section').hide();
    $('.Select-preferred-fit-section').hide();
    $('.Experience-section').hide();
  $('.gender-section button.back-btn').on('click', function() {
    
        $('.gender-section').hide();
        $('.weight-section').show();
   
  });
  
    
    $('.Female-Body-shape-section').hide();
    $('.Select-preferred-fit-section').hide();
    $('.Experience-section').hide();
  $('.gender-section button.Male').on('click', function() {
    
       $('.Body-shape-section').show();
        $('.gender-section').hide();
   
  });
   

    $('.Female-Body-shape-section').hide();
    $('.Select-preferred-fit-section').hide();
    $('.Experience-section').hide();
  $('.Body-shape-section button.back-btn').on('click', function() {
    
        $('.Body-shape-section').hide();
        $('.gender-section').show();
   
  });
  
    $('.Female-Body-shape-section').hide();
    $('.Select-preferred-fit-section').hide();
    $('.Experience-section').hide();
  $('.gender-section button.Female').on('click', function() {
    
       $('.Female-Body-shape-section').show();
        $('.gender-section').hide();
   
  });
  
    $('.Select-preferred-fit-section').hide();
    $('.Experience-section').hide();
  $('.Female-Body-shape-section button.back-btn').on('click', function() {
    
        $('.Female-Body-shape-section').hide();
        $('.gender-section').show();
   
  });
  
   $('.Select-preferred-fit-section').hide();
    $('.Experience-section').hide();
  $('.select-male-s button.Male').on('click', function() {
    
       $('.Select-preferred-fit-section').show();
        $('.Body-shape-section').hide();
   
  });
  
  $('.Select-preferred-fit-section').hide();
    $('.Experience-section').hide();
  $('.select-male-r button.Male').on('click', function() {
    
       $('.Select-preferred-fit-section').show();
        $('.Body-shape-section').hide();
   
  });
  
  $('.Select-preferred-fit-section').hide();
    $('.Experience-section').hide();
  $('.select-male-l button.Male').on('click', function() {
    
       $('.Select-preferred-fit-section').show();
        $('.Body-shape-section').hide();
   
  });
  
    $('.Select-preferred-fit-section').hide();
    $('.Experience-section').hide();
  $('.select-female-s button.Female').on('click', function() {
    
       $('.Select-preferred-fit-section').show();
        $('.Female-Body-shape-section').hide();
   
  });
  
  $('.Select-preferred-fit-section').hide();
    $('.Experience-section').hide();
  $('.select-female-r button.Female').on('click', function() {
    
       $('.Select-preferred-fit-section').show();
        $('.Female-Body-shape-section').hide();
   
  });
  
  $('.Select-preferred-fit-section').hide();
    $('.Experience-section').hide();
  $('.select-female-l button.Female').on('click', function() {
    
       $('.Select-preferred-fit-section').show();
        $('.Female-Body-shape-section').hide();
   
  });
  
   $('.Experience-section').hide();
  $('.Select-preferred-fit-section button.back-btn').on('click', function() {
    
        $('.Select-preferred-fit-section').hide();
        $('.gender-section').show();
   
  });
  
    $('.Select-preferred-fit-section').hide();
    $('.Experience-section').hide();
  $('button.tight').on('click', function() {
    
       $('.Experience-section').show();
        $('.Select-preferred-fit-section').hide();
   
  });
  
  $('.Select-preferred-fit-section').hide();
    $('.Experience-section').hide();
  $('button.standard').on('click', function() {
    
       $('.Experience-section').show();
        $('.Select-preferred-fit-section').hide();
   
  });
  
  $('.Select-preferred-fit-section').hide();
    $('.Experience-section').hide();
  $('button.lesstight').on('click', function() {
    
       $('.Experience-section').show();
        $('.Select-preferred-fit-section').hide();
   
  });
  
  $('.Experience-section button.back-btn').on('click', function() {
    
        $('.Experience-section').hide();
        $('.Select-preferred-fit-section').show();
   
  });
  
     });
  
</script>
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Best suggestion is you save the original for safe keeping. Then try what you can yourself. Learn to use the browser developer tools (F12) console to check for any script errors. Then if things are not working show what you tried along with a detailed explanation of what is and what's not working

Comment: I suspect you may have back end processing issues by removing part of the data that gets submitted and that will be a lot more of an issue than just removing the html which is relatively simple